# Expansion of bash array when using scp

Tags: bash

I am trying to retrieve several files using scp.
I already know the paths of the files to get on the remote, so I decided to add them in an array:

```
declare -a array
array+=("path/to/file1")
array+=("path/to/file2")
array+=("path/to/file3")

scp "$USER@$HOST:${array[@]}" .
```

outputs:

```
path/to/file1
cp: cannot stat `path/to/file2': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `path/to/file3': No such file or directory
```

Only the first file gets copied. The scp command only takes the first file into account, then cp is invoked for the remaining files.

Something as simple as this makes it work:

```
declare -a array
array+=("path/to/file1")
array+=("path/to/file2")
array+=("path/to/file3")

string="${array[@]"
scp "$USER@$HOST:$string" .
```

outputs:

```
path/to/file1
path/to/file2
path/to/file3
```

When I launch my script with bash -x, it shows that with the array, the command is not properly quoted:

```
+ scp $USER@$HOST:path/to/file1 path/to/file2 path/to/file3 .
```

Contrary to the string version:

```
+ scp '$USER@$HOST:path/to/file1 path/to/file2 path/to/file3' .
```

What exactly is causing this ? And is there a way to make the array version work, or should I use a string every time I want to use scp ? (which could be quite inconvenient with special characters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding an array with `@` results in multiple arguments:

```
$ array=(foo bar baz)
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${array[@]}"
<foo>
<bar>
<baz>
```

Expanding it with `*` results in a single argument separated by the first character in `$IFS`:

```
$ array=(foo bar baz)
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${array[*]}"
<foo bar baz>
```

99% of commands expect one filename per argument, but `scp` for historical reasons uses multiple filenames per arguments. In this case, you can therefore use

```
scp "$USER@$HOST:${array[*]}" .
```

though you'll likely want to escape the filenames as well, again for historical scp reasons:

```
scp "$USER@$HOST:${array[*]@Q}" .
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Are rsync and ssh also using multiple filenames per arguments ? I use those commands alternatively with scp, so I tested it and your answer with ${array[*]} seems to work for rsync too, while ${array[@]} does not.

Comment: `ssh` joins all its arguments with spaces and evaluates the result with the remote shell (similar to what `eval` does for the local shell), and needs to be quoted and escaped accordingly, so yes. `rsync` currently does multiple files per argument, but aims to drop this at some point in the future (see `--protect-args` in the manual). Obviously at that point each of the multiple arguments will need a `host:..` prefix, which [glenn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67628402/1899640) shows how to add.

Comment: Ok, thanks again ! Do you know where I can get detailed information about how commands are processing arguments ? Is it available somewhere in the man pages ? Also why are most commands opting out of multiple files per argument, is it to better handle filenames with spaces or other special characters ?

Comment: It's sloppy behavior and therefore often sloppily documented (`man rsync` mentions it, but mostly as part of documenting that they don't want to do that anymore). The question is rather why some commands allow it, and it's because they pass it to a remote shell. For `scp` and `rsync`, this was likely to allow remote globbing. For `ssh`, this was probably to be drop-in compatible with `rsh`

Answer (score 2):

We can substitute `printf` for `scp` to see what it actually expands to:

```sh
$ printf '>%s<\n' "$USER@$HOST:${array[@]}"
>user@host:path/to/file1<
>path/to/file2<
>path/to/file3<
```

Which is not what you want: you need to attach the user&host to each array element.

The `${var/pattern/string}` expansion can be used here:

```sh
$ printf '>%s<\n' "${array[@]/#/$USER@$HOST:}"
>user@host:path/to/file1<
>user@host:path/to/file2<
>user@host:path/to/file3<
```

This is a tricky one:

- we have the "var" as `array[@]` -- that expands to each array element
- the pattern is `#`, which means "the empty string anchored at the start of the string
- and the replacement string is the user&host.

---

Expanding the files array into a brace expression for the remote host:

```sh
$ remote_files=$( IFS=","; printf '%s@%s:{%s}' "$USER" "$HOST" "${array[*]}" )

$ printf '>%s<\n' "$remote_files"
>user@host:{path/to/file1,path/to/file2,path/to/file3}<
```

Comment: That's clever ! I didn't know about this expansion. I will try to remember it, it might come in handy

Comment: I tried your method, but since the remote access is password protected, I need to type the password for each file I want to copy. Is there any way around it ?

Comment: My scp man page says it does glob matching, but I don't know if you can do brace expansion. Try, manually, `scp "$USER@$HOST:{path/to/file1,path/to/file2,path/to/file3}" .`

Comment: Also, `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id` for password-less ssh/scp'ing

Comment: I tried with the braces, it works but I don't know if it's very practical to substitue the array in a script to have the braces and the comas at the right spots.

I tried ssh-copy-id but I can't seem to make it work for now, despite my key being added to the authorized_keys file, I will look into it later. I don't have much rights on the remote.

Comment: But your solution is working perfectly with rsync though !   
`rsync -ave ssh "${array[@]/#/$USER@$HOST:}" .` copies all files and asks for the password only once